# Objects change shape during render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

The wire frame cages made from Ico Spheres with a subdivision modifier and a wire frame modifier change during rendering. Happens in both evee and cycles.

[image: TOP VIEWPORT. BOTTOM RENDER]

Comment: Are any of your modifiers disabled for renders? Any chance you hid an object in the viewport? (will still be visible in render)

Comment: because your screenshots isn't very helpful, could you provide blend file please?

Comment: It looks like you have different values set for Viewport and Render in some of your Subdivision Surface modifiers.

Comment: FIXED. There were different values set. Thank you. Learned something.